# How to intuit P(win the same lottery twice) $= p^{2}$ vs. P(win the same lottery twice | you won the lottery once) $= p$?

Tags: conditional-probability, lotteries

Each lottery draw is independent, with probability $0 < p ≪ 1$. $W_i$ denotes the event of winning the $i^{th}$ draw of the same lottery. I seek intuition, not asking about computations.

##### $\Pr(\color{green}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2}) = p^{2}$

["the probability of winning the lottery multiplied by winning the lottery the second time"](https://old.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/38si94/high_school_mathprobability_of_winning_a_lottery/crxmy45/), because ["the two events *are* independent. In other words, winning the lottery once doesn't some how increase or decrease your chances of winning it a second time."](https://old.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/38si94/high_school_mathprobability_of_winning_a_lottery/crxq4eq/)

##### $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | {\color{Green}{W_1}}) = \dfrac{\color{crimson}{\Pr(W_2)}  \cap  \color{Green}{\Pr(W_1)}}{\color{Green}{\Pr(W_1)}} = \dfrac{\color{crimson}{\Pr(W_2)}  \times  \color{Green}{\Pr(W_1)}}{\color{Green}{\Pr(W_1)}} = \dfrac{\color{red}{p} \times \color{limegreen}{p}}{\color{limegreen}p} = p.$

> [“If someone already wins the lottery, then the chance that the person wins the lottery a second time will be exactly the same as the probability they win the lottery if they had not previously won the lottery before,” Harvard statistics professor Dr. Mark Glickman tells CNBC Make It.](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/05/31/harvard-prof-on-odds-of-winning-multiple-lotteries-like-these-people.html)

> [If you've *already* won the lottery in week one, however, the odds of winning the next week will be unaffected by the outcome and so remain the same as for any other individual event](https://old.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/pni9s/lottery_lightning_strikes_twice/c3qro0g/).

#### My misgivings

$\Pr(\color{green}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2}) \neq  \Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1})$ feels contradictory. Intuitively, why doesn't  $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1}) = p^2$?

Doesn’t a player's ["odds for winning the next time are the same as if they'd never played before"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3209757)  contradict $\Pr(\color{green}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2})= p^{2}$. How can I reconcile these 2 probabilities intuitively?

$\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1}) = p$ feels deceitful. Given that you won the lottery once, $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1}) = p$ implies that winning again is the same probabilistically as your first win! But this is wrong! $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1}) = p$ *OUGHT*, but wholly fails to, disclose that winning any lottery twice is way less probable than winning it once.

I ask not about [$\Pr($you win a lottery at least twice) $= 1 - \Pr($you never win) $- \Pr($you win the lottery once)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3233269).

Comment: You seem to have written that $P(W_2)=p^2$, which is incorrect

Comment: @Sambo Thanks! I corrected this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It feels contradictory that $\Pr(\color{green}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2}) \neq  \Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1})$.  Intuitively, why aren't these two probabilities equal?

> I feel that $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1})$ *OUGHT* $= p^{2}$ because  $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1})$ *OUGHT* capture, but wholly fails to disclose, that $\Pr(\color{green}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2}) ≪  \Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | \color{green}{W_1})$.

$\def\Wone{\color{green}{W_1}}
\def\Wtwo{\color{crimson}{W_2}}
$(Revision 8 of the question)

I am confused, do you expect $\Pr(\Wone \cap \Wtwo) \ll \Pr(\Wtwo \mid \Wone)$, but at the same time feel contradictory that $\Pr(\Wone \cap \Wtwo) \neq  \Pr(\Wtwo \mid \Wone)$?

---

I am missing how your intuition relates $\Pr(\Wtwo\mid\Wone)$ and $\Pr(\Wone\cap \Wtwo)$. Their ratio ($\ne 1$) exactly discloses how (un)likely $\Wone$ is:

$$\Pr(\Wone\cap\Wtwo) = \Pr(\Wone)\Pr(\Wtwo\mid \Wone) \ll \Pr(\Wtwo \mid \Wone)$$

As $\Pr(\Wone) = p \ll 1$, this value also discloses that $\Pr(\Wone\cap\Wtwo) \ll \Pr(\Wtwo \mid \Wone)$.

Intuitively to me, the probability of achieving both $\Wone$ and $\Wtwo$ is the product of

- the probability of $\Wone$, and
- the probability of $\Wtwo$ given that one already achieved $\Wone$.

---

How do you see the meanings of $\Pr(\Wtwo\mid\Wone)$ and $\Pr(\Wone\cap \Wtwo)$ alternatively, and see a contradiction?

Comment: sorry! I made some typos. Does my edit change your answer? I meant to compare $\Pr(\color{limegreen}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2})$ with $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2} | {\color{limegreen}{W_1}})$, NOT $\Pr(\color{limegreen}{W_1})$ as you wrote.

Comment: @user1791055 $\def\Wone{\color{green}{W_1}}
\def\Wtwo{\color{crimson}{W_2}}
$I am confused, do you expect $\Pr(\Wone \cap \Wtwo) \ll \Pr(\Wtwo \mid \Wone)$, but at the same time feel contradictory that $\Pr(\Wone \cap \Wtwo) \neq  \Pr(\Wtwo \mid \Wone)$?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I am VERY sorry. I miscommunicated...my fault for confusing you. Does my edit change your answer?

Comment: @user1791055 I don't have a new response to revision 9 yet, as I would still quote the same inequality mentioned in your [revision 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4686622/7):$$\def\Wone{\color{green}{W_1}}
\def\Wtwo{\color{crimson}{W_2}}\Pr(\Wone\cap\Wtwo) = \Pr(\Wone)\Pr(\Wtwo\mid \Wone) \ll \Pr(\Wone)$$Having $\Pr(\Wtwo\mid\Wone)=p\ll1$ is consistent with "winning any lottery twice is way less probable than winning it once".

Answer (score 1):

> Intuitively, why aren't these two probabilities equal?

Let $W_i$ denote the event of winning on the $i$th lottery, for the sake of brevity.

$P(W_1 \text{ and } W_2)$ measures how likely it is to win two lotteries, from the very start. You have not won any lotteries and know nothing yet about your outcomes, just the probability of winning a single lottery.

For $P(W_2 \mid W_1)$, you are ***given*** that you won the first lottery. You may think of it as knowing, at this moment in time, you have ***already*** won it (or ***will*** win it if you'd rather frame this as being at the start). You only have one more lottery in front of you to participate in as a result (at least, only one more that you could possibly lose), and hence the probability of winning the second lottery is just the probability of winning that lottery (because you have already won one).

Comment: "You only have one more lottery in front of you to participate in as a result (at least, only one more that you could possibly lose), and hence the probability of winning the second lottery is just the probability of winning that lottery (because you have already won one)." But this feels misleading and wrong because this overlooks, and wholly fails to disclose, that $\Pr(\color{crimson}{W_2}) = p^{-2} ≪ \Pr(\color{green}{W_1}) = p^{-1}$.

Comment: Made and fixed a typo that might clarify it a bit.

Comment: But ultimately, the idea is that winning the second lottery, knowing you've won one, is functionally identical to just winning one lottery. Your winning of the past lottery has no bearing on this present one. When calculating the odds of winning both, you're making a conjecture about what will happen after two lottery drawings in the future; when calculating the odds of winning one, knowing you've won one, you're making a conjecture about what happens one lottery drawing in the future, knowing a result already, but that doesn't affect the future one.

Comment: Put differently, $P(W_1 \text{ and } W_2)$ is about two random events, whereas $P(W_2 \mid W_1)$ is about a random event happening after another event happens, this other event ($W_1$) being one known to happen for sure (or at least assumed as much)

Comment: Many thanks!  *"But ultimately, the idea is that winning the second lottery, knowing you've won one, is functionally identical to just winning one lottery."*  $\color{peru}{(1)}$ I still cannot intuit this, because this feels like disregarding $\Pr(\color{green}{W_1} \cap \color{crimson}{W_2})$. And this appears to contradict your next sentence, where you refer to the knowledge that you won once. *"Your winning of the past lottery has no bearing on this present one."*" $\color{peru}{(2)}$ Then why does the knowledge that you won once matter, which you used in your previous sentence?

Comment: In some sense, it doesn't matter, that is precisely the point: because the lotteries do not influence each other, the probability of winning a future lottery is not affected by winning one right now. You just now have to be aware of the fact that the goal is now to win one further lottery, not two.

Answer (score 0):

> It feels contradictory that P(you win the same lottery twice) ≠
> P(you win the same lottery twice|you won the lottery once). Intuitively, why aren't these two probabilities equal?

Foremost, they describe two distinct things.  Namely they are measured under different conditions.

The *joint probability* measures your expectation that you will win both when you have **no** knowledge of the lottery outcomes.

The *conditional probability* measures your expectation that you will win the second *should* the first be won.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not feel this resolves my misgivings. Please elaborate? Even after I win the first lottery, why ought winning again be easier? Why does knowledge that I won a first time, make winning again easier? Knowing whether I win a first time, shouldn't affect the fact that winning any lottery twice is way less probable than winning it once.

Comment: It does not make winning *again* easier as they are independent.   Conditioning on winning the *first* makes winning the *first* more probable.

Comment: "Conditioning on winning the first makes winning the *first* more probable." $\color{Sienna}{(1)}$ Doesn't this sentence contradict $Pr(W_i) = p \; \forall i$? Winning any draw has the same probability. $\color{Sienna}{(2)}$  And how does this sentence make sense? If you condition on winning the first draw, then you already won the first draw. Conditioning on a past event can't make that past event more probable, because it already happened!

Comment: Certainty is the most probable you can get.

Comment: I am still befuddled. Please expound?